# Finding roots of the equation $\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}+\sqrt{x^2+7x-8}=\sqrt{5(x^2+3x-4)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Many helping books and also book mention the root of equation is $1$ and $-3$, but I think there is only root $1$.
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}+\sqrt{x^2+7x-8}=\sqrt{5(x^2+3x-4)}$$

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please write better. It is even hard to edit.

Comment: For $x=-3$ I obtain $\sqrt{0}+\sqrt{-20}=\sqrt{-20}$. This looks fine, so the book is right.

Comment: $1$ is definitely a solution. Plugging in $x=-3$, the equation becomes $\sqrt{-20}=\sqrt{-20}$. Whether this is true depends on how you interpret square roots of negative numbers.

Comment: But -3 is not contain in domain also seems complex numbers

Comment: $\sqrt{-20}=\sqrt{-20}$ is always true, independently how we interpret square roots of negative numbers. The question doesn't mention a domain for $x$. Why should $x\neq -3$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, but just a bit of pragmatism. If the question is from a Pre-Calculus textbook, likely the question is implicitly asking for real roots, not complex. Perhaps I am taking too much liberty in my assumption, however.

Comment: @codeing_monkey Actually, it is the book which says that it is right. So it is not our responsibility whether or not we are taking too much liberty. One could have both opinions.

Comment: I guess it depends on interpretation and the context in which you are solving it. If you insist on finding the points where $$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}+\sqrt{x^2+7x-8}-\sqrt{5(x^2+3x-4)}$$ cuts the $x$-axis then indeed, $x=-3$ is **not** a root in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you solve the equation by removing square roots you obtain the equation
$$4x^4 + 36x^3 + 12x^2 - 148x + 96 = 9x^4 + 36x^3 - 18x^2 - 108x + 81$$
which gives you $x = 1, -3$. However, we must verify that these are indeed solutions to our original equation (with square roots) and you are correct that only $x = 1$ is true.
Of course, this is assuming you are working only in $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{C}$ since you have indicated that this is a question for a book on Pre-Calculus.

Comment: Mean if for precalculus then only root 1 is correct?

Comment: I don't think so. This is only convention, which isn't mentioned in the question. The domain for $x$ is real numbers. Nevertheless $\sqrt{-n}=\sqrt{-n}$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ is certainly true. We may forbid to write that expression, but why should we? Even if we don't know what it is, it is a tautology.

Comment: @IbrarTahir -3 is a complex root while 1 is a real root. Both are roots of the equation. Like Dietrich implies, whether or not you allow for complex roots is entirely dependent on the context of the question.

Comment: But -3 is not the domain of the function so how can it becomes root?

Comment: @IbrarTahir I am assuming you are working in the domain of real numbers. Therefore, only $x = 1$ is a root. If you extend your domain to complex numbers, then $x = -3$ is also a root because, in this field, square roots of negative numbers are well-defined.

Comment: Alright it it the book of "algebra and trigonometry" and there is nothing mention about in which domain to work complex or real  so I have to take real domain?

Comment: I would have to say then you are probably working in the reals since, by definition, the domain of the square root function is $[0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Ok I got the point

Comment: @IbrarTahir Please consider accepting my answer if you think it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Denote $a = \sqrt{x^2+2x-3}$ and $b = \sqrt{x^2+7x-8}$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
&5(x^2+3x-4) = 4(x^2+2x-3) +(x^2+7x-8) = 4a^2+b^2\\
&\iff a+b = \sqrt{4a^2+b^2}\\
&\iff a^2+2ab+b^2 =4a^2+b^2\\
&\iff \cases{a=0
\\2b = 3a}\\
&\iff \cases{(1): x^2+2x-3 = 0 
\\(2):4(x^2+7x-8) = 9(x^2+2x-3)}
\end{align}$$

The case $(1)$ has two roots $x = 1$ and $x = -3$.

The case $(2)$ has 1 root $x = 1$.

We need to put $x = 1$ and $x =-3$ to test the equation. Only the root $x = 1$ satisfies the equation (the roots $x = -3$ make the second term $x^2+7x-8$ negative, so we need to remove it).

By consequence, only the equation has only $1$ root $x = 1$.

Comment: Both are roots? Or only x=1 root

Comment: @IbrarTahir $x = 1$ is the unique root of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Cancel common factor $(x-1)$ from under the radical $x\ne 1$.Then
$$\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+8}=\sqrt{5(x+4)}$$

Can you square and simplify?

Comment: I solve it my question is that x=1 and x=-3 both are roots or only x=1 is root

Comment: Whether you can cancel $\sqrt{x-1}$ without the assumption $x>1$ seems to be at the core of the OP's question.